# How do I insert into a record a value of the current time in MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
INSERT INTO cat_herder.cat (id, name, breed_id, secondary_breed_id, date_modified)
VALUES("asdfs-ab1234-jhgb2-34jh", "Meowsers", 0,1, TIME.NOW())
```

`TIME.NOW` appears not to work even though heidisql suggests it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just need NOW() not TIME.NOW()

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`NOW()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) this way:

```
INSERT INTO cat_herder.cat (
    id, 
    name, 
    breed_id, 
    secondary_breed_id, 
    date_modified) 
VALUES (
    "asdfs-ab1234-jhgb2-34jh", 
    "Meowsers", 
    0,
    1, 
    NOW());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try simply `now()`, you don't need the `time.` part.